# Get this tag off of the [display]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

[display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/display)

Excerpt:

> Display refers to a style property in CSS. Common values include - but are not limited to - block, inline-block, inline, table, flex, none.

No tag wiki.

1,667 questions

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
   No. Only 455 questions are tagged with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) as well.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   It is covered by [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css). Other uses vary, some are definitely off-topic.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   No. Covered by title, body or code example, or completely superfluous.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   No. It could mean a [physical display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58187754/1839439), [CSS-display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58214542/1839439), [display the contents of something](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58240503/1839439), [abstract concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58131722/1839439), [buggy behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58022500/1839439), [screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57936421/1839439), and [other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58007196/1839439), [...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57351308/1839439), [...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57184854/1839439), [...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57012995/1839439), [...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56295954/1839439)

Question count over time:
[image]

Comment: or we can rename it [css-display]

Comment: @temani Do we need it? A significant clean up effort would still be required.

Comment: no sure which one requires less effort. Burnination or renaming (and later synonym if needed). I would vote for the simpliest one.

Comment: #display { tag:burninated }

Comment: @RobertColumbia more like `.display-tag { display:burninated; }`

Answer (score 8):

The [display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/display) tag is indeed ambiguous. The tag holds

- [110+ **Python** questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/display+python)
- [13 **R** questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/display+r)
- [99 **Java** questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/display+java)
- [130 **PHP** questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/display+php)
- [200+ **javascript** questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/display+javascript)
- [**Other** 700+ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/display+-php+-css+-r+-java+-python+-javascript)

The tag info *clearly* states that the tag refers to a [style property in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/display/info) but the tag is not being used for the same purpose. Renaming the tag won't make these questions go away. I suggest two approaches to handle the tag (this one saves the tag).

Cleaning up the tag from the questions that do not belong to the CSS style property and making [display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/display) tag a synonym of [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) as we already have a [css-display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-display) [lying as one of the synonyms of](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/synonyms) [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).

The magnitude of questions requiring edits will be around 1230 questions then approx to edit. It seems like a *really* big number.

Another alternative would be to just burninate the tag and re-tag questions with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).

Comment: BTW the tag you are proposing already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/synonyms

Comment: I would actually be against making display a synonym of CSS, just looking at the number of CSS-unrelated questions we have at the moment. In future someone comes and wants to ask how to change resolution in Windows and it will be tagged with CSS by accident.

Comment: @Dharman that is not how this tag should be used. I stated that this should be synonymized with CSS just because of the tag info. The info should state that this tag should not be used to refer to a monitor display or about _any_ output device.

Comment: We already have the description say it should only be used for CSS, and people still ask questions about other stuff. My point being that if we synonymize it with CSS we are not solving the problem. Burninating this tag would be a better option IMHO.

Comment: @Dharman I wasn't inclined towards the burnination more because of the tag's name. Even if we carried out a tight and careful burnintion there's a high chance of it arising again in the very future. I'd rather not waste people's time into burninating tags that have a tendency like that. Synonymizing it will solve the problem more than burination here. If we look closely.

Comment: Of course, some of the `javascript` questions could conceivably be about altering the CSS `display` property via the CSSOM. It is an alarmingly common question in that tag.

Comment: Display should just not exist. That way nobody can misuse it, for any purpose. The misusage is too common case that a synonym would make worse.

Comment: I agree with Braiam, it's way too broad to be a useful tag where someone could have some expertise.